# Distributing array components over processors using Open MPI with C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmpi

I am trying to write a simple C++ program that takes an array, sends equal portions of it to different processors, and those processors do computations on the components and then send the portions of the array back to the master processor to be combined in the final array.

I have started with a simple case where I have an array of size 2, and the first component gets added by 1 by process 1. The second component gets added by 2 by process 2.

Here is what I have:

```
# include <cstdlib>
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
# include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
# include "mpi.h"

using namespace std;

ofstream debug("DEBUG");
ofstream debug1("DEBUG1");
ofstream debug2("DEBUG2");

// Declare the array
double arr[2];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 MPI::Init(argc, argv);

// Make the array
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2; 

int rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
int npes = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();

if ( rank == 0 ) {
  cout << "Running on "<< npes << " Processes "<< endl;
  double arr1;
  double arr2;
  MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&arr1, 1, MPI::DOUBLE, 0, 0);
  debug << "arr1: " << arr1 << endl;

  /*... Program freezes here. I'd like to combine arr1 and arr2 into
arr*/
}

if ( rank == 1){
  debug1 << "This is process " << rank << endl;
  double arr1 = arr[0];
  debug1 << "arr1: " << arr1 << endl;
  arr1 = arr1 + 1;
  debug1 << "arr1+1: " << arr1 << endl;
  MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&arr1, 1, MPI::DOUBLE, 0, 0);
}

if ( rank == 2){
  debug2 << "This is process " << rank << endl;
  double arr2 = arr[1];
  debug2 << "arr2: " << arr2 << endl;
  arr2 = arr2 + 2;
  debug2 << "arr2+2: " << arr2 << endl;
}

cout << "Greetings from process " << rank << endl;
MPI::Finalize();
}
```

I am compiling with

`mpiCC test.cpp -o test`

and running with

`mpirun -np 3 test`

since I wish to use 2 processors to operate on `arr` and 1 processor (process 0) to gather the components.

My issue is that the program freezes when using

`MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&arr1, 1, MPI::DOUBLE, 0, 0);`

on process 0.

Does anyone know why this would happen? I'd simply like to distribute computations on an array over processors and thought this would be a good example to start with.

Comment: First of all, the MPI C++ set is deprecated, so it is advisable to use the C-bindings. Second, does all the data always has to go back to the master, i.e., does the master contain the full array?

Comment: Shouldn't processor with rank=2 be sending half the array?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use C++ because of compatibilities with other existing codes that I am using.

Comment: Yes, processor with rank=2 should be sending half the array but I can't seem to get processor with rank=1 to properly send its half.

Answer (score 0):

When you use MPI, there are functions designed for that kind of task. MPI_Scatter and MPI_Reduce. It allows you to divide your array to n children do your computations and get the result back to the coordinator.